# I don't know why my http request doesn't work in my angular project?

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, httpclient

I created a RESTful API with node.js and when I tested it with postman it worked properly and showed correct result.

But my problem is in request from my angular application. when I send a request, there is no reaction in API and it seems no request is sent to server at all!

My API url is:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/menus/menujsonexport
```

And when I send a request via postman it return a json correctly.

And here is my request script in angular:

```
private requestMenu(type: 'listsidemenu'): Observable<any> {
  let base;
  if (type === 'listsidemenu') {
    base = this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/api/menus/menujsonexport'
            , { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.getToken()}` }});
  }

  const requestMenu = base.pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      return data;
    })
  );
  return requestMenu;
}
```

I called the request with this method :

```
public fetchjsonmenu() {
  this.authserv.listSideMenu()
  .pipe(
    finalize(() => {console.log('finished'); }),
    tap(x => {
      console.log(x);
    })
  );
}
```

But there is no reaction in my nodejs API.

Do you have any idea?

Please tell me if there is lack of information to answer to this question.

Comment: Are you getting any error ? if yes please mention

Comment: @Mridul There is no reaction from server. I'm confused.

Comment: Did you allow CORS ?

Comment: @Mridul I didn't check it. but I have another api url that acts normally in the same way.

Comment: in fetchjsonmenu you're not subscribing.. if that's intentional (i.e. you want to return an observable and subscribe elsehwere on invokation, then you need to remember to add a return statement!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Observable instance begins publishing values only when someone subscribes to it. You subscribe by calling the subscribe() method of the instance, passing an observer object to receive the response.

`.subscribe` is not an Angular2 thing.

It's a method that comes from rxjs library which Angular is using internally.

If you can imagine yourself when subscribing to a newsletter and after subscribing, every time that there is a new newsletter, they will send it to your home (the method inside subscribe gets called).

That's what happens when you subscribing to a source of magazines ( which they call it `Observable` in `rxjs` library)

All the AJAX calls in Angular is using this library behind the scene and in order to use any of them, you've got to use the method name, e.g get, and then call subscribe on it, because get returns and Observable.

Also, when you're doing this `<button (click)="doSomething()">` Angular is using `Observables` behind the scene and subscribes you to that source of thing, which in this case is a `click` event.

Back to our analogy of `Observables` and `newsletter stores`, after you've subscribed, as soon as and as long as there is a new magazine, they'll send it to you unless you go and unsubscribe from them which for that to happen you've got to remember the subscription number or id, which in rxjs it would be like :

```
let subscription = magazineStore.getMagazines().subscribe(
   (newMagazine)=>{

         console.log('newMagazine',newMagazine);

    });
```

And when you don't want to get the magazines anymore:

```
   subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Also, the same goes for

```
 this.route.paramMap
```

which is returning an `Observable` and then you're subscribing to it.

My personal view is `rxjs` was one of the greatest things that were brought to JavaScript world and it's even better in Angular.

There are 150~ `rxjs` methods ( very similar to `lodash` methods) and the one that you're using is called switchMap

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `.subscribe()` in your code after the get call.For more information check the [link](https://angular.io/guide/observables).
So, now your script should look something like this.

````
  let base;
  if (type === 'listsidemenu') {
    base = this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/api/menus/menujsonexport'
            , { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.getToken()}` }}).subscribe();
  }

  const requestMenu = base.pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      return data;
    })
  );
  return requestMenu;
}```
````